# Really Basic Graphics in C# 2.0 Tutorials

Tags: graphics, c#-2.0

I work for a ticketing agency and we print out tickets on our own ticket printer. I have been straight coding the ticket designs and storing the templates in a database. If we need a new field adding to a ticket I manually add it and use the arcane co-ordinate system to estimate where the fields should go and how much the other fields need to move by to accomodate new info.

We always planned to make this system automate with a simple (I stress the word simple) graphical editor. Basically we don't forsee tickets changing radically in shape any time soon, we have one size of ticket and the ticket printer firmware is super simple because it's more of an industrial machine, it has about 10 fonts and some really basic sizing interactions.

I need to make this editor display a rectangle of the dimensions by pixel of the tickets (can even be actual size) and have a resizable grid which can toggle between superimposition and invisibility on top of the ticket rectangle and represented by dots rather than lines.

Then I want to be able to represent fields by drawing rectangles filled with the letter "x" that show the maximum size of the field (to prevent overlaps). These fields should be selectable, draggable and droppable in a snap to grid fashion.

I've worked out the maths of it but I have no idea how to draw rectangles and then draw grids in layers and then put further rectangles full of 'x'es on top of those. I also don't really know much about changing drawn positions in accordance with mouse events. It's simply not something I've ever had to do.

All the tutorials I've seen so far presume that you already know a lot about using the draw objects and are seeking to extend a basic knowledge of these things. I just need pointing in the direction of a good tutorial in manipulating floating objects in a picturebox in the first place.

Any ideas?

Comment: What level are you at with C# and WinForms? Have you managed to create a form with controls, display it and respond to user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you in need of a guide to this unusual (at least those of us with a BIS background) field I would heartily endorse:

https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145656/http://bobpowell.net/faqmain.aspx

I am now happily drawing graphical interfaces and getting them to respond to control inputs with not too much hassle.